# How to find the tangential acceleration when a function is given with a constant as unknown?

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> A crystal is moving on an horizontal plane $x-y$ by the given law:
>   $r(t)=\left(12t\hat{i}+ct^2\hat{j}\right)\,m$ with $t$ being the time on seconds
>   and $c$ a positive constant with given acceleration units. If for $t=0$
>   the radius of curvature is $4\,m$. Find the tangential acceleration
>   for $t=2\,s$.

The given alternatives are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{216}{37}\sqrt{37}\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
2.&216\sqrt{37}\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
3.&\frac{\sqrt{37}}{37}\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
4.&\frac{72}{37}\sqrt{37}\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
5.&\frac{144}{37}\sqrt{37}\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly how to tackle this problem:

It seems obvious that it is needed the value of $c$ because with that, then I could obtain an expression from where it can be taken its derivative consecutively and with that the acceleration.

But the thing is if I do plug in the initial condition from t=0

The whole equation becomes zero.

$r(t)=(12t\hat{i}+ct^2\hat{j})$

$r(0)=(12t\hat{i}+ct^2\hat{j}) = 0$

So what can be done here?.

I cannot assume that the radius of curvature $4$ will be the same for $t=2$.

Can somebody help me here?.

Answer (score 1):

Your velocity is $v=(12,2ct)$ and your acceleration $a=(0,2c)$. Since $v(0)=(12,0)$ at $t=0$, at that moment all the acceleration is normal (no tangential). Therefore, 
$$
a(0)=a_N(0)=\frac{v(0)^2}{R(0)}= \frac{144}{4}=36.
$$
This implies $2c=36$ or $c=18$. Next, you find $v(2)=(12,72)$. 
We know $a(2)=(0,36)$. To find the tangential part, just project in the direction of the velocity,
$$
a_T(2)=(0,36)\cdot (12,72)/\|v(2)\|=36\cdot 72/\sqrt{5328}=36\cdot 72/12\sqrt{37}=216/\sqrt{37}=216\sqrt{37}/37,
$$
which is your option (a).

Comment: When you mentioned about ***all acceleration is normal*** what you mean with **normal**?. Is it tangential?. The formula which you're using is referring to tangential acceleration. Can you please specify?. I'm confused. **Why** $2c=36$. Do you mean that $a(0)=(0,2c)$? I am understanding here that $a(0)=a(2)$?. The part where you mentioned about to get the tangential project in the direction of the velocity and the calculation which it follows ***I dont understand***. ***Why*** $(0,36)\cdot\frac{(12,72)}{\left\|v(2)\right\|}$?.

Comment: What is it $\frac{(12,72)}{\left\|v(2)\right\|}$ the unit vector?. Can you please explain to me this part?

Comment: The acceleration is a vector. It has a tangential component and a normal component. Your initial velocity is horizontal (it has no component in the vertical direction) and your acceleration is the vector $(0,2c)$ at all times, so it is vertical. Therefore, at $t=0$ your tangential component of the acceleration is zero and there is only the normal part, which is known to be equal to $v^2/R$, where $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity and $R$ is the radius of curvature. To find the projection of a vector in some direction you have to dot multiply it by a unit vector in that direction.

Comment: To get a tangential unit vector you divide the velocity by its magnitude, since the velocity vector is tangent to the path. In this case it is $v/\|v\|=(12,72)/\|v\|$ and $\|v(2)\|=\sqrt{12^2+72^2}=\sqrt{5328}$

Comment: Yes, $a(t)=(0,2c)$ at all times as you can see by taking the second derivative of your position. I am using the same letter $a$ to denote both the acceleration vector and its magnitude for simplicity, should be clear from the context. However, $a_T$ and $a_N$ are always scalars (scalar projections).